# How could a ballistic mask provide full protection without compromising the wearer's singing voice?

Tags: science-based, engineering, armors, audio

So, I'm having trouble with one of my character designs.

Guardian angels are former humans who died in such dumb ways that Heaven simply couldn't let them in, not before they proved they can prevent a person from dying if they had to. They rarely materialize in physical form, and when they do, they have to make the most use of it, usually by keeping it out of harm's way via body armor.

Erik is a guardian angel, who wears a modified version of the standard-issue ballistic mask 24/7, as his actual face looks like a blend between supreme leader Snoke and the Red Skull. This poses some problems as Erik really likes to sing and when he doesn't have his way, he screams, he stomps, and threatens to bomb the opera house.

**The mask has to be homogenous and to protect the entire face against ballistic threats. Just how the heck is a mask supposed to satisfy those dependencies without altering the wearer's singing voice?** Erik doesn't want to sound like either Bane or Gerard Butler when singing with the mask on.

Being a guardian angle, he can make just about anything for himself that doesn't violate the laws of physics. His goal is for others to hear his singing voice crisp and clear, even on the battlefield and even if it's created by a (high-quality) speaker. However, he wants everything to be live, so no pre-recorded audio, please.

Comment: maybe try ventriloquism?

Comment: What is a ballistic mask?

Comment: @AlexP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_face_mask

Comment: Thank you, appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

> His goal is for others to hear his singing voice crisp and clear, even on the battlefield and even if it's created by a (high-quality) speaker.

So just have a fully-enclosed soundproof helmet, a high-quality mike within it, and then just attach a speaker to the outside.